# Purpose of the "offset" parameter in GHC.Prim's (index/read/write)(type)OfAddr# functions

Tags: haskell, primitive-types

What is the purpose of the "offset" parameter in GHC.Prim's `...OfAddr#` functions?

As stated in the documentation this parameter can be used to specify offset in number of elements or bytes when accessing memory at given addres. But since we have address arithmetic (`plusAddr#` and others), it's always possible to provide an exact address.

Does using of offset have any advantages or disadvantages over calculating address directly? I.e. is there any difference between `readInt32OffAddr# addr# 1 ...` and `readInt32OffAddr# (plusAddr# addr# 4) 0 ...`?

If there is no difference, why this parameter exists at all? Just legacy or is there any reason to use it? What is the recomended approach to use `...OfAddr#` if any?

Comment: I have no idea, but maybe it's just for convenience. Even C has `v[i]` as a shortcut to `*(v+i)`, and even the latter implicitly multiplies `i` by `sizeof *v`. Not sure about why this is a primitive instead of an helper function, though.

Comment: If I had to guess it is because `readInt32OffAddr#` and `readWord32Array#` primops are implemented by the same machinery behind the scenes, and because latter needs an offset it was easier to keep an offset for primops that work on `Addr#` as well. That is just my speculation though.

Comment: @chi Your've got a sensible intuition. Yes, using of such functions may provide some convenience if we don't want to worry about calculating an address. But GHC.Prim-s was never meant to be functions called by a regual programmer. They are co called 
"prim ops" (https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/prim-ops) extremely low-level operations, meant to be injected by the compiler itself, or for low-level scenarios. As you have noticed, any custom wrapper can make them more user-frienly. But what was the reason to overcomplicate prime ops themself?

Comment: @schernichkin: the primitive operations are compiled to C--, so if C-- supports such feature it might be a useful that code can take advantage of it, since the C-- compiler might have optimization techniques for `v[i]`. But I'm not an expert in this.